# Find the equation of tangent.

Tags: geometry, slope

**Original Question:** Find the equation of the tangent at point P of parabola $x^2=4y$, which is at the minimum distance to center of a circle $x^2+y^2+6x+8=0$.

*What i did:*

- Found coordinates of center of circle i.e. $(-3,0)$
- Equation of tangent at point $P(h,k)$, $hx-2y-2k=0$.

Now how to proceed further?

Comment: It isn’t clear to me at all. The title seems little more than a restatement of part of the problem. Please show your work.

Comment: The general formula for tangent at given point (h,k) for this parabola will be $xh = 2(y+k)= 2(y+\frac{h^2}4)$. Now,apply distance formula to get distance between this line & (-3,0) and minimize that distance to know the points of parabola

Comment: @AloknathFurr did you get the formula by taking derivative?

Comment: Your perception of question is wrong. It is asking for the minimum distance between tangent line & centre of circle. Not between point of parabola and centre of circle.

Comment: For a general line ax+by+c =0, distance between this line & some point $(x_0,y_0)$ is defined to be length of perpendicular from the point to the line and is given by $d = \frac{ax_0 + by_0 +c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Comment: Hint: minimum distance is zero.

Comment: @amd no it isn't. the parabola and circle never touch so the minimum distance is greater than 0.

Comment: Hint: The normal line to the parabola at a point must pass through the circle's center for the distance to be minimized.

Comment: Minimum distance can still be zero, as the tangent to parabola may still pass through centre of circle. In fact, it is coming out to be zero.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley The question is not clearly worded. You’re reading it as requiring the point on the parabola to be at a minimal distance; I’m reading it as requiring the tangent line to be at a minimal distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need the distance formula to solve this problem. Just a clear and intuitive understanding of geometry. Remember that if you have a line in space, and a point not on that line, the shortest distance between point and line make a right angle. Because of this property, the shortest distance between the circle's center and the parabola should make a right angle. That is to say, the normal line of the parabola must pass through the circle's center.

So first, we must find the equation of the normal to the parabola $y=x^2/4$. Simple enough, we can use point-slope form: $y-y_0 = m(x-x_0)$ where we'll plug in our point $(a, a^2/4)$. The slope of a normal line is the inverse reciprocal of the tangent. $y' = \frac{x}2$ --> normal slope = $-\frac2x$.

Equation of normal line: $y-\frac{a^2}4 = -\frac2a(x-a)$.

This normal line at point $a$ must pass through the center of the circle, which you've found (correctly) to be $(-3,0)$. So... Plug and solve!

$$0-\frac{a^2}4=-\frac2a(-3-a)$$
`Simplify`
$$-\frac{a^2}4=\frac6a+2$$
`I multiplied by 4a`
$$-a^3=24+8a$$
$$a^3+8a+24=0$$
This has one solution, at $a=2$. At that point is the minimum distance between the parabola and the center of the circle. On the parabola, this would be the point $(2,1)$. Now we can find the tangent line at that point! Remember, slope of the tangent line is $\frac{x}2$.

$y-1=\frac22(x-2)$ ------> $y=x-1$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w3y243i0qm

Comment: Thanks it really helped

Comment: I changed my question before viewing your answer, Sorry for that.And i appriciate the time you spent for making graph

Comment: i am also in high school, are you on facbook or twitter ?so i can share my future math problems with you.

Comment: $a=-2$ , hence $x+y+1=0$, Anyways i just wanted the algorithm

Comment: Glad this helped @Aman, and for future math problems, always use Math SE. Great place to get help, and I might pop up again! You're welcome!